# Google Maps Marker's squished with animation being performed

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, backbone.js, marionette

When I add a marker with `animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP` the marker is squished (it's width is smaller than normal) while the drop animation is being performed.

This only happens when the animation is being performed.
Once the animation is complete the marker goes back to it's normal size.

Some clarification:
This is being performed in a Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.

The related code is:

```
// For each model add a marker
_.each(this.model.models, function (model) {
    var coordinates = model.get('coordinate'),
        position = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude),
        marker;
    // Don't add the same marker twice.
    if (!this.markers[model.get('id')]) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            title: model.get('name'),
            map: this.map
        });
        // Save the marker
        this.markers[model.get('id')] = marker;
    }
    // Extend the bounds of the map
    bounds.extend(position);
}, this);
this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Please post your code, we aren't magicians here.. Well some of us might be.

Comment: or better, make a jsfiddle.com example.. this kind of issue is usually too hard to debug if it can't be reproduced.